# Rails: making use of rich join tables while collecting data from related tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Forgive me if this has been answered already.
I have searched for a while and I suspect i am asking the wrong question therefore getting the "wrong" answers

I have a rails project with 3 controllers with corresponding views and a model
I have resourceful routes for them and can perform CRUD on each of them
- Cards
- Sets
- JoinCardSets

The database schema for them are:

table name: cards

```
id
cardName
description
imageUrl
```

table name: sets

```
id
setName
description
imageUrl
```

table name: join_card_sets

```
id
card_id
set_id
no_of_cards
```

cards and sets have a many to many relationship so my models look like the following:

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :join_card_sets
  has_many :sets, :through => :join_card_sets

end


class Set < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :join_card_sets
  has_many :cards, :through => :join_card_sets

end

class JoinCardSet < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :set
  belongs_to :card

end
```

When I navigate to CardsController#Show

It display:
Card name,
description,
And with some rails magic the sets that are linked to it through the join table

Controller:

```
def show
    @mtg_card = Card.find(params[:id])
    @current_sets = @mtg_card.mtg_sets
end
```

"Show" view:

```
<h2><%= @card.name %></h2>
<%= @card.description %><br>
<img src="<%= @card.imageUrl %>" alt="<%= @card.name %>"><br>

<% if @current_sets.present?
  @current_sets.each do |t| %>
   <%= t.name %>: <%= %>
  <% end #end of for each loop current_set |t| %>
<% end #end of if statment %>
```

What I need help with is with the following:
When @current_sets loops through each connection,
I would like it to pick up the "no_of_cards" column and display it along with the card set name.

If its not to clear or you know where the answer lie, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick in using ActiveRecord is to find the right point in your web of associations such that the objects you're iterating over either themselves have enough information for your view or have associations you can traverse to get to that information. `Set` objects in your schema have many card_join_sets, so there's no way to get a single relevant "no_of_cards". `JoinCardSet` objects only have one set, so it's easy to get to the relevant set to get a name.

In the controller:

```
    @current_join_sets = @mtg_card.join_card_sets
```

Then in your view:

```
 @current_join_sets.each do |t| %>
   <%= t.set.name %>: <%= t.no_of_cards %>
  <% end #end of for each loop current_set |t| %>
```

(In real code there is more to clean up here., `t.set.name` breaks the [Law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), and you should be eager-loading data, but that's off-topic for this question.)

Comment: I reading up on Clean Code by Robert Martin, I think he touches on the The Law of Demeter. I have a lot to learn :-) and refactor lol